# formatting code after numeric list doesn't display properly

Tags: bug, code-formatting, list

So I've just edited a question and noticed that if I enter a code block after a numeric list:

> 1. in Addbill form the User insert items to the the DB(NewBill Table).
> 2. in Bill form is a reportview show the data from NewBill table, but it doesn't show. my Query in the dataset is;
>
>    SELECT CID, IID, Con, Title, Price, TPrice, Qun, Date FROM dbo.NewBill WHERE CID = @CID
>      And CON = @CON

It isn't displayed as code, just tabbed out:

---

1. in Addbill form the User insert items to the the DB(NewBill Table).
2. in Bill form is a reportview show the data from NewBill table, but it doesn't show. my Query in the dataset is;

   SELECT CID, IID, Con, Title, Price, TPrice, Qun, Date FROM dbo.NewBill WHERE CID = @CID
   And CON = @CON

---

example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209751/reportviewer-delay-to-show-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue. Just indent a *further* 4 spaces:

1. in Addbill form the User insert items to the the DB(NewBill Table).
2. in Bill form is a reportview show the data from NewBill table, but it doesn't show. my Query in the dataset is;

   ```
   SELECT CID, IID, Con, Title, Price, TPrice, Qun, Date 
   FROM dbo.NewBill WHERE CID = @CID
   And CON = @CON
   ```